# Junit expectMessage AssertionError

Tags: java, junit

This is the code I want to test

```
public static Map<String, String> JSON2Map(String urlParams) {
    String [] params = urlParams.split("&");
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String param : params) {
        String[] kvs= param.split("=");
        if ( kvs.length>1)
        map.put(kvs[0], kvs[1]);
    }
    return map;
}
```

This is my junit test:

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void JSON2MapTest() throws Exception {
    exception.expect(NullPointerException.class);
    exception.expectMessage("send null will occur NullPointerException");
    JSONUtils.JSON2Map(null);       
}
```

When I run the test it throws:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: (exception with message a string containing "send null will occur NullPointerException" and an instance of java.lang.NullPointerException) 
got: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

if I comment out `//exception.expectMessage?(....)` then it will pass.

Whats happen about the `exception.expectMessage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the test fails is because of:

```
exception.expectMessage("send null will occur NullPointerException");
```

this code is asserting the message that is returned with the exception, but there is none.

[Here](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.be/2012/09/testing-expected-exceptions-with-junit.html) is an example how you could write code and test the expected message:

```
public class Person {
  private final int age;

 /**
   * Creates a person with the specified age.
   *
   * @param age the age
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the age is not greater than zero
   */
  public Person(int age) {
    this.age = age;
    if (age <= 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid age:" + age);
    }
  }
}
```

The test:

```
public class PersonTest {

  @Rule
  public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

  @Test
  public void testExpectedException() {
    exception.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    exception.expectMessage(containsString("Invalid age"));
    new Person(-1);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, the method that I want test is the other PG writed, if didn't throw the Exception, so I cant catch the matcher String, so, How shold I write the error message when it throws Exception when the method didn't throws exception?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want? You want to know how to test unchecked exceptions?

Comment: I have to test the otherones' codes, so if they didn't  try&catch the exception, and today I want to show the message if it didn't throw the exception I expected, I should I do ?

Comment: @crowngym I think you should best ask a new question and show us what you expect, it's easier then trying to understand and solve it in comments.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to test a method while expecting an Exception is to use the following annotation

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
```

where the test case fails if no `IllegalArgumentException` had been thrown.

Edit: `org.junit.Test` javadoc:

> ```
> /**
>  * Optionally specify <code>expected</code>, a Throwable, to cause a test method to succeed iff
>  * an exception of the specified class is thrown by the method.
>  */
> Class<? extends Throwable> expected() default None.class;
> ```